# How to append XHR HTML partial when the responseType = document

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, single-page-application, partials

I am developing an SPA and the library I have to use to get partials got updated. Now it is setting the xhr.responseType = document based on the extension of the file that im requesting which in this case is .html

The local library I use to print the response to the browser uses innerHTML to replace the view of a container and insertAdjacentHTML to append to it. This isn't working anymore because the response is now an HTML document instead of plain text, all I get printed to the webpage is:

> [object HTMLDocument]

Also now the response is wrapped automatically with "html", "head" and "body" tags

How do I handle such response to append it to a container or replace the contents of the container?

The first thing I tried was

```
outputDiv.innerHTML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(response);
```

But it is too hackish to convert it from an html document to string and then manipulate it with regex to remove the html, head and body tags and parse it again to HTML with innerHTML.

Then I tried

```
<div id="fullWrapper">
    <p>Container full of content</p>
</div>


myXHR('modules/menu/views/menu.html', function(response) {
        const outputDIV = document.getElementById('fullWrapper');
        outputDiv.appendChild(response.documentElement);
    });
```

By miracle it works in chrome but the problem with this approach is that it also appends the HTML HEAD and BODY opening and closing tags and the partial content, so the partial menu.html containing only the next code

```
<p>Partial content</p>
```

becomes

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

<p>Partial content</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and when I append it with the above code, the result is not what id call semantic ;)

```
<div id="fullWrapper">
    <html>
        <head></head>
    <body>

    <p>Partial content</p>

    </body>
    </html>
</div>
```

I also tried

```
<div id="fullWrapper">
    <p>Container full of content</p>
</div>


myXHR('modules/menu/views/menu.html', function(response) {
        const outputDIV = document.getElementById('fullWrapper');
        outputDiv.appendChild(response.documentElement.querySelector('element'));
    });
```

This works "well", when the partial has only one child but I won't necessarily know which element or elements will come in the partial, so a more generic approach would be preferred.

### Edit 1

I could also iterate over each children, also could append it to a document fragment to avoid repaint when the partial has lots of nodes.
Anyway this approach also does not feel right. There must be a better way.

```
<div id="fullWrapper">
    <p>Container full of content</p>
</div>


myXHR('modules/menu/views/menu.html', function(response) {
        const outputDIV = document.getElementById('fullWrapper');
        let children = response.documentElement.querySelector('body').children);
for (let item of children) {
    outputDiv.appendChild(item);
}
    });
```